# How to get string value from an OracleParameter object when using ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net

As the code Shows below, I want to insert a row into a database table (oracle 11) and return a **String-Value** of the inserted row.

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into foo values('foo','bar') returning idString into :lastIdParam";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("lastIdParam", OracleDbType.Varchar2), ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // returning 1 (insert row successfully)

    var result = cmd.Parameters["lastIdParam"].Value.ToString();   // == String.Empty
}
```

*Debugging shows that lastIdParam.Value's value = Empty.String:*
[image]

My Problem is, that **I'm not getting the return string into my return-parameter** but it will work when returning an integer value (like sequence no of inserted id). Cast Problem? ...?

The idString is filled if running the Statement directly (or if I just do something like `returning 'ABC' into :myOutputParameter`

Any ideas how to retrieve a string after inserting row?

Comment: what if you use `var result = (int) cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: What does *not working* mean? Doesn't it compile? Doesn't it return anything? Does it return a wrong value? Does it throw an exception? Please provide an exact description including the full error message if applicable.

Comment: @JWiley Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ExecuteNonEquery.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery is returning an int: Signature = public override int ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @Codo The screenshot above shows the debug result. So it is compiling and the return value is always an empty string

Comment: How is your `idString` column defined?

Comment: @Codo idString = Varchar2(128), but like I said it won't work neither if using this statement: insert into foo values('foo','bar') returning 'ABC' into :lastIdParam

Comment: Have you tried setting a size for the parameter? Like this: `new OracleParameter("lastIdParam", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128)`

Comment: @Codo That's it! Setting the size for the parameter solves the Problem!! Thank you very much! (Transform your comment into an answer to set this question as solved!)

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting a size for the parameter? The default size is 0.

```
new OracleParameter("lastIdParam", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `idString` is an expression which has no value in your context, unless it is a column name in your table. Therefore, it is epected to be empty. You may change your query like the example below and see what happens.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into foo values('foo','bar') returning hereYouHaveToUseAColumnFromTheFooTable into :lastIdParam";
```

Comment: Yes, it's importand that `idString` is the name of a column otherwise you will get an error (ORA-06550).